# Hide nav bar on scroll Function

Tags: javascript, dom

if prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos. How could this be true ? when prevScrollPos is 0 and currentScrollPos never less than 0

```
var prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  //Here
  if (prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: Are you want `#navbar{position:sticky;top:0;}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prevScrollPos` gets updated at the end of your function, so when you scroll up, `currentScrollPos` will be less than `prevScrollPos`.

Also, you've got a typo:

```
prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
```

Comment: Thank you bro, this is what i've been looking for

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for the code, it is helpful, however, on mobile, it produces an issue.
If you forcefully scroll to the top, the logo does not appear because it registers as a page refresh (even though it is not) and the menu does not appear. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function get_scroll() {
  if(window.scrollY > 30)
  {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";

  }else{
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  }
}

document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].setAttribute("onscroll","get_scroll()");
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some comments to your code this may clear your doubt.

```
var prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
// here if we assume the prevScrollPos as 0 then when the user scrolls the function gets executed.
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  // Here, say currentScrollPos = 50px; so if condition fails and else block gets executed.
  if (prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  // since the prevScrollpos is being updated here, it will be greater than 0(will be 50px) next time.
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

and when the user scrolls up then the function gets called again and this time the if condition satisfies because 50px(prevScrollPos) will be greater than 0(current assuming he scrolled all the way up).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. it's very clear for me now